# min-width media query always fires while max-width query never fires

Tags: css

I'm trying to set a media query that fires when the screen is wider than 600px. For some reason, the query always fires when set to min-width and never fires when set to max-width regardless of how wide the window actually is in either scenario.

```
#vision {
    font-size: 8rem;
}

@media screen
and (min-width: 600px) {
    #vision {
        font-size: 7rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see what your max-width looks like.

Comment: @eclipsis What I mean is if I change the statement from min-width to max-width, the rule never fires regardless of screen width. I'm not running them concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code you've provided.

My test: https://jsfiddle.net/wp8z9aue/

```html
<h1 id="vision">Test</h1>
```

```css
#vision {
  font-size: 8rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #vision {
    font-size: 7rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, it's working fine... Perhaps my view was zoomed and I didn't realize?